# Tag Dialog Hover To Contain Additional Links to Manage Tag Favorites

Tags: feature-request

On the main page when hovering over a tag, a user can `subscribe` to email alerts and `rss`:

[image]

How about adding the ability to `Add To Favorites` and `Add to Ignore` by a simply mouse click which would supplement that existing *manual* functionality?

---

### Current Add/Ignore Functionality

[image]

Comment: You can click the star to toggle between "Favorite", "Ignored", and normal. (I suppose that could be a little more obvious...)

Comment: @Kendra wow that's an obscure but awesome feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can already do this. The little star in the tag info box has three states.

Normal:

[image: normal non-favorited and non-ignored tag]

A click on the star favorites the tag:

[image: favorited tag]

Another click ignores the tag:

[image: ignored tag]

Clicking on it when ignored sets the tag back to normal.

This is a little obscure, but when you consider how the star on questions works, it makes a little more sense.

Comment: +1 and +300 super unicorn rainbow points for freehand circles with freehand arrows and freehand writing.

Comment: @NathanOliver What's sad is that writing is neater than my normal non-computer writing. >.>

Comment: You need this then: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/4f/24/b7/4f24b77a93cb19106a62dd830a516ab5.jpg

Comment: @NathanOliver That is so going on my desk at work, right between my Umbreon plushie and my Venom mug.

Comment: Anyone with *crazy* writing gets my attention. :-) Thanks for pointing out that obscure operation.