# Feature Request : quick tag favorite/ignored option

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

A very simple feature, in the hover popup of tags, one could add an option to add it as a favorite or ignored one.

As I start to help some people (very humblely I admit), it bother me to see questions I dont understand a thing, but it can be tedious to add tags as ignored.

Don't you think ?

Comment: 3 votes to close as unclear? How is that? While I don't think it's needed, it is very obvious that Dan wants to be able to have an option to add a tag as favorite/ignored when hovering that tag. Instead of going over to the right and clicking add/ignore and typing in the tag name.

Comment: If this does get reopened, it should be closed as a duplicate of [Tag Dialog Hover To Contain Additional Links to Manage Tag Favorites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305888/tag-dialog-hover-to-contain-additional-links-to-manage-tag-favorites/305889#305889)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a feature to do this. When you hover over a tag, a tooltip will appear. In the top left corner of the tooltip there's a star. Clicking on that star will toggle between favorite, ignored and normal.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that existed and I'm guessing the OP didn't either. Not extremely obvious, I suppose, and I never pay much attention to the hover on tags. Have an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, it feels so warm and cuddly like a kitten :)

Comment: Exactly, kinda expected it to be already existing, but cannot see where it was. Thanks. Maybe I should change my post to question instead of feature-request ?