# Hide questions with specific tags

Tags: feature-request

It should be possible to hide questions with specific tags. E.g. there are often appearing questions with `vue.js` or `angular.js` and more, but I can't answer them. It should be possible to filter them out.

[image]

Comment: you can add them to ignored tags

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @SurajRao, I still don't get it, there is only "Favorite Tags" but there is no "Ignored Tags". See the screenshot in my updated question.

Comment: click on edit in favorite tags. You should see ignored tags section below favorite

Comment: @SurajRao, ok wow... I would never find this out by myselve. Why is it hidden in Favorite???

Comment: You can also do this by hovering over the tag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305889/2607247

Comment: Mental note: run query to figure out if people actually find the ignore functionality on a regular basis. If memory serves, it used to be a more prominent feature, closer to the top. I can see why it eluded you.