# Add to favorites/ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think it’s a great idea to add the quick actions “add to favorite” and “add to ignored” in the tag pages. With this feature, it will be easier to add tags in favorites or in ignored.

### 1. For the quick view of tags

[image: Illustration image to show the quick action buttons]

### 2. For the tag’s page

[image: Illustration for the buttons on the tag’s page]

### Update

Like [@SebastianSimon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) says, the star in the top left corner does that. It’s a tri-state button. By default the star is gray. Clicking it will turn it gold and add it to your favorites. Clicking it again will turn it to a red cross and add it to your ignored tags. Clicking it again resets it. But I also agree with [@AndréKool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4916627/andr%C3%A9-kool) who said *“But to be honest I also absolutely didn’t expect the star to also be used for ignoring. I would expect a simple on/off functionality for setting it as a favorite...”*. So we should, maybe, remove the star to add some clearer buttons.

---

The images are just illustrations, I’m not pretending that I’m a UX/UI designer.

Comment: The star in the top-left corner already does that.

Comment: @AndréKool It’s a three-state button. By default the star is gray. Clicking it will turn it gold and add it to your favorites. Clicking it again will turn it to a red cross and add it to your ignored tags. Clicking it again resets it.

Comment: @Xufox Cool, I never knew that. But to be honest I also absolutely didn't expect the star to also be used for ignoring. I would expect a simple on/off functionality for setting it as a favorite...

Comment: Highly related, would be a dupe if you didn't add the part about making it make more sense: [Tag Dialog Hover To Contain Additional Links to Manage Tag Favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305888/tag-dialog-hover-to-contain-additional-links-to-manage-tag-favorites) (Also totally shameless plug for my radical free-hand red writing on those images.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow made an update, they change the star button for clearer buttons :

[image]

Also, they change the tags pages :

[image]